# Received w-2 never received money

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-2

My granddaughter received 2 w-2’s for money she was never paid.  She goes to college and thought she was volunteering to help with a cross country event at another university.  All the students that participated received w-2’s.  She said they were all taken into a room and told to complete paperwork.  She didn’t know what it was but I’m guessing it was a W-4.  Is this legal?

Comment: What did the organization that issued the W-2 say about it?

Comment: This is either Unclear What You're Asking or a Duplicate.  More details could clarify which.  In particular, when asked, what does the organization that issued the W-2 say about it?  Will they give you a copy of the paperwork that she completed?